# AS3: Not getting typeError when calling a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm writing my own language from ActionScript as a personal project (yeah, I guess AS3 is not the best language to build a language from, but never mind that).

**NOTE:** I have checked several times, and my compiler's option 'Enable Strict Mode' is set to `True`. I have tried setting it to `False` to try, but I didnt get a different result.

At any rate, I have a this:

```
package NodyCode.Classes 
{

    public class NCString 
    {

        var value:String;

        public function NCString(expression:String = "") {
            value = expression;
        }


        public function rindex(substr:NCString, startIndex:int = 0x7fffffff):uint {
            //code here
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm writing my own language, I need to make sure functions and methods can take un unlimited number of arguments. For this reason, I'm using an anonymous function so that I can use the `apply` method. Like so:

```
//This code is in a class named ClassMethods
public static var StringMethods:Object = {
    rindex: function(substr:NCString, startIndex:int = 0x7fffffff):uint {
        return this.rindex(substr, startIndex);
    }
}
```

And, somewhere else in my code, I do the call:

```
return ClassMethods.StringMethods["rindex"].apply(ncstr1, [ncstr2, [5]]);
```

I would like an error to be thrown whenever the user uses the wrong type of argument.

So, in this case, I call the `rindex` method on `ncstr1`, with arguments: `substr = ncstr2` and `startIndex = [5]`. Notice that, according to my anonymous function's definition, `startIndex` is supposed to be an `int`, **not** an `Array`.

So, I expected an error to be thrown. Instead, though, `rindex` is called with `startIndex = 5`.

Why is `[5]` converted to `5`, and is there any way for me to prevent that? If there isn't, I can always work around this problem, but I'd rather not if I can do otherwise.

*EDIT: Finally understood that I did not mention I was using an anonymous function.*

Comment: `'foo'` doesn't seem correct either, as it's not an instance of `NCString`. Seems like the compiler is being funny here though, it shouldn't be happy with this at all

Comment: Hi. Yeah, I didn't make clear that `'foo'` was also a NCString instance. Changed now.

Comment: in strict mode there should be an error thrown since you pass a Array type where int is expected. In fact as it is there should even be a warning since you are not returning anything but you expect a uint return. You must have strict mode off.

Comment: @BotMaster I understand, now. I hadn't mentioned I was using an anonymous function. I edited my first post.

Comment: @AnthonyD. Ahhh, ok... totally expected.. this is a quirk of AS3 and the AVM; a single element array [5] also equals an int value of 5, while an int array [5,7] has an int value of zero (0).... have to deal with this `weirdness` in PlayScript...

Comment: @SushiHangover That's so strange, never realized this in all the years I worked with AS3. @AnthonyD It would be difficult to typecheck the parameters passed to `apply`, especially without generics, and thus you can pass whatever you feel like in that Array and the compiler won't complain.

Comment: @JKillian I never knew it either till I was x-compiling some AS3 Starling games via PlayScript (.Net/Mono) and had very strange issues runtime issues and backtracked it to the original code using that quirkiness... ASC creates the correct types and the ABC reflects the types correctly, but the AVM does what it does... that is what happens when you have a language with no formal language specification ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here's what was said in the comments:

I did have my compiler on `strict` mode. The reason for which I was not getting an error is because I was using the `apply` method of an anonymous function. The type checks are loosened when using the `apply` method. That's why `[5]` was coerced to `5`.

There is apparently no way to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling with [strict mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67670-7fd5.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7eaf) set to false? (See [here also](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.htm).)

The `strict` option: "Prints undefined property and function calls; also performs compile-time type checking on assignments and options supplied to method calls".

It defaults to true, but if it got set to false somehow, compile-time checks might be disabled. I'd check your compiler settings (whether in an IDE or if you're compiling on the command-line) and make sure they're correct.

Comment: No, strict mode is set to true.

Comment: @AnthonyD This answer should be it. In AS3 the literal `[5]` will define a int[] type (integer array) with a single element and using the compiler option `-strict=true` will cause your question code example to fail with a 1067 error (Implicit coercion). I would look at your compiler options again...

Comment: OK, I understand now why I don't get any compile error. I didn't mention that I'm calling `rindex` via the `apply` method of an anonymous function.

Comment: My question still stands, though.